# Property chaining and isset in configuration object

Tags: php, arrays, oop, configuration, chaining

I couldn't find a question that was quite like mine, but if you can find one feel free to let me know..

I'm trying to figure out how to effectively create an neat configuration object.

I want the object (or a config manager of some sort) to be able to convert an array or INI file into a parent/child grouping of objects.

Eg:

```
$config_array = array ( 
    'somecategory' => array ( 'key' => 'somevalue' ), 
    'anothercategory' => array ( 'key' => 'anothervalue', 'key2' => 'anothervalue2' ),
);

$config = new Configuration_Array( $config_array );

echo $config->somecategory->key; // prints: 'somevalue'
```

I have effectively done this with the following code:

```
class Configuration_Array extends Configuration
{

protected $_child_class = 'Configuration_Array';
protected $_objects = null;
protected $_config = null;


public function __construct( $config_array = null, $child_class = null ) {
    if ( null !== $config_array ) {
        $this->setConfig( $config_array );
    }
    if ( null !== $child_class ) {
        $this->setChildClass( $child_class );
    }
}

public function __get( $name ) {
    $name = strtolower( $name );
    if ( ! isset ( $this->_objects[ $name ] ) ) {
        $this->_createObject( $name );
    }
    return $this->_objects[ $name ];
}

public function __isset( $name ) {
    $name = strtolower( $name );
    return ( ( isset ( $this->_objects[ $name ] ) ) or $this->_can_create_object( $name ) );        
}


public function reset() {
    $this->_objects = null;
}

public function toArray() {
    if ( ! is_array ( $this->_config ) ) {
        throw new Exception( 'No configuration has been set' );
    }
    return $this->_config;
}

public function setConfig( $config ) {
    if ( null === $config ) {
        return $this->reset();
    }
    if ( ! is_array ( $config ) ) { 
        throw new Exception( 'Configuration is not a valid array' );
    }
    $this->_config = $config;
}

public function loadConfig( $path ) {
    if ( ! is_string ( $path ) ) {
        throw new Exception( 'Configuration Path "' . $path . '" is not a valid string' );
    }
    if ( ! is_readable ( $path ) ) {
        throw new Exception( 'Configuration file "' . $path . '" is not readable' );
    }
    $this->setConfig( include( $path ) );
}

public function setChildClass( $class_name ) {
    if ( ! is_string ( $class_name ) ) {
        throw new Exception( 'Configuration Child Class is not a valid string' );
    }
    if ( ! class_exists ( $class_name ) ) {
        throw new Exception( 'Configuration Child Class does not exist' );
    }
    $this->_child_class = $class_name;
}

public function getChildClass() {
    if ( ! isset ( $this->_child_class ) ) {
        throw new Exception( 'Configuration Child Class has not been set' );
    }
    return $this->_child_class;
}


protected function _createObject( $name ) {
    $name = strtolower( $name );
    if ( ! isset ( $this->_config[ $name ] ) ) {
        throw new Exception( 'No configuration has been set for object "' . $name . '"' );
    }
    $child_class = $this->getChildClass();
    if ( is_array ( $this->_config[ $name ] ) ) {
        $child = new $child_class( $this->_config[ $name ], $child_class );
    } else {
        $child = $this->_config[ $name ];
    }       
    return ( $this->_objects[ $name ] = $child );
}


protected function _can_create_object( $name ) {
    $name = strtolower( $name );
    return isset ( $this->_config[ $name ] );       
}

}
```

**The Problem**

Most of this works perfectly, but I am having some trouble figuring out how I can use *isset* effectively. With property chaining, *isset* only works on the last value in the chain, eg:

```
if ( isset ( $config->somecategory->key ) ) {
```

Which uses the object returned by $config->somecategory and checks whether it holds an object called 'key'

This means that if $config->somecategory doesn't exist, an exception is thrown. The user would have to do this to check effectively:

```
if ( isset ( $config->somecategory ) and isset ( $config->somecategory->key ) ) {
```

But that seems quite annoying.

An array on the other hand doesn't need to be checked at each level; PHP can check the entire thing:

```
if ( isset ( $config[ 'somecategory' ][ 'key' ] ) ) { // No error/exception
```

What I'm looking for is a way to implement my class so I can treat my objects sort of the same way I'd treat an array:

```
if ( isset ( $config->somecategory->key ) ) {
```

In a way that wouldn't throw an exception if 'somecategory' doesn't exist...

Ideas?

Comment: I'm confused a bit. You're calling it method chaining yet your examples are accessing members (not methods), e.g., `$config->somecategory->key` instead of `$config->somecategory()->key()`. Furthermore, `isset` can only be used with variables, not method return values.

Comment: Haha I'm an idiot. I've been reading up on method chaining so it's the first thing that came to mind. I guess you'd call it property chaining..? I'll edit the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

The only problem is, you would have to call `isEmpty` to check if a configuration is given, and `get` to get the final value. (Like can be seen in the 3 test cases at the bottom)

```
<?php
// set debug
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

class Config
{
    protected $data;

    public function __construct($data = null) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        return isset($this->data[$name]) ? new Config($this->data[$name]) : new Config();
    }

    public function isEmpty() {
        return empty($this->data);
    }

    public function get() {
        return $this->data;
    }
}

$test = new Config(array(
    'foo' => array(
        'bar' => array(
            'barfoo' => 1
        )
    )
));


// test 1
if (!$test->foo->bar->isEmpty()) {
    print_r($test->foo->bar->get());
}

// test 2
if (!$test->foo->bar->foobar->isEmpty()) {
    print_r($test->foo->bar->foobar->get());
}

// test 3
if (!$test->foo->bar->barfoo->isEmpty()) {
    print_r($test->foo->bar->barfoo->get());
}
```

Example:

http://codepad.org/9EZ2Hqf8

Comment: I do kind of like this option, but the fact that I'd have to use accessor function is a bit annoying. Although there doesn't seem to be any win-win options with my problem.. Hmm.

Answer (score 3):

Since PHP 7 it's possible to use [a not well documented feature of null coalesce operator](https://markshust.com/2017/08/25/php-7s-null-coalesce-operator-usage-objects-and-arrays/) for this purpose.

```
$config_array = [ 
    'somecategory' => [ 'key' => 'somevalue' ], 
    'anothercategory' => [ 'key' => 'anothervalue', 'key2' => 'anothervalue2' ],
];

// Quickly convert to object
$json = json_encode($config_array);
$config = json_decode($json);

echo $config->somecategory->key ?? null; // prints: 'somevalue'
echo $config->somecategory->missing_key ?? null; // no errors but also doesn't print anything
echo $config->somecategory->missing_key->go->crazy->with->chains ?? null; // no errors but also doesn't print anything
```

Here is an [online example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8befd075694c3435a5d4f96497e04fc90ed95ff6) in action

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not version of `isset` which checks your property chain correctly. Even writing your own method will not help as passing the chain as parameter to your method already fails if `somecategory` is already unset.

---

You can implement the magic method for accessing unset properties (maybe in a base class common to your config objects). This will create a dummy object of class `UnsetProperty` and return that.

Your class to `$config->someCategory->key` will deliver a `UnsetProperty` for `$config->someCategory`. This object will also delivery a new `UnsetProperty` for `$obj->key`. If you implement a method `IsSet()` in `UnsetProperty` returning false and in other properties returning true you can simplyfy your check to:

```
if($config->someCategory->key->IsSet()) ...
```

This will need a lot of to do so I am not sure if you do not like to go with the chained isset-calls.

```
if((isset($config->someCategory)) and (isset($config->someCategory->key))) ...
```

Depends on style and how many nested levels you have.

Hope you get the idea behind the possibility.

Comment: Note that you can actually shorten `if` by making use of multiple arguments in `isset`, i.e. `isset($config->someCategory, $config->someCategory->key)`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php. As `isset` docs state: "If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered."

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Zend_Config](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.html). It operates almost exactly as you describe.

You could use it directly or simply as an instructional guide to build your own.

Comment: That seems to be quite like what I want, thanks. But, the class doesn't seem to have any failsafe to prevent against a failure if a key doesn't exist.
Say I try to access $config->something->name, but 'something' isn't set as data in the $config instance. This would mean we're trying to call 'name' on a null value. Unless I've missed something..

Comment: Right, looks like you have to manually perform your own `isset()` checks: `if (isset($config->something->name)){ // do something }`. Then even if the `something` key is not set, you won't get an error.

Comment: But if `something` isn't set, that would throw an error or exception, because you're trying to check the existence of `name` in `null`, not in a `something` object. The class I have now works quite well, the only problem I have is this same issue, because isset is only called on the last member, not all of them individually

Comment: When I run the code: `isset($obj->something->name)`, I simply get false, no error. Same behavior even if `$config` is merely a `stdClass` instance.